# What is $2\sec^2(x)$ evaluated at $5\pi/6$?

Tags: trigonometry

What is $2\sec^2(x)$ evaluated at $5\pi/6$?

I don't know when to apply the squared part of the secant identity.

Now that I know when to apply the square....
doing this part of the equation I get -2.66666666667. Then I'm supposed to subtract this value from 3-sinx) which I solved to be 2.5. However when I do this I do not obtain the right answer and I'm wondering where I went wrong.

Comment: Re: new part of question (third paragraph): anything squared is positive, so $-2.66\cdots$ cannot be correct.

Answer (score 2):

The notation $\sec^2x$ means $(\sec x)^2$.  So, first calculate $\sec x$ then square it.  (And then multiply by $2$.)

This notation is commonly used for  trigonometric and hyperbolic functions:

- $\sin^2 x$ means $(\sin x)^2$;
- $\tan^3\theta$ means $(\tan\theta)^3$;
- $\cosh^5t$ means $(\cosh t)^5$.

It is also occasionally used for  other functions: $\ln^2x$ is sometimes written for $(\ln x)^2$.  You may need to carefully read the context to decide what is meant.

However, **warning**: $\sin^{-1}x$ **never** means $(\sin x)^{-1}$, it means the inverse sine of $x$, sometimes written $\arcsin x$.

Comment: @user46944 It originally said $-2$ in the title but I see that has now been changed.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

$$sec(\theta) = \frac{1}{cos(\theta)}$$

$$cos(\frac{5\pi}{6}) = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$

$$2sec^2(\frac{5\pi}{6}) = 2*\frac{2^2}{3} = \frac{2^3}{3}$$